# Oracle SQL - Define the year element of a date dependent on the current month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a view in SQL Developer based on this statement:

`SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE START_DATE > '01-JUL-2020'`

The year element of the date needs to set to the year of the current date if the current month is between July and December otherwise it needs to be the previous year.

The statement below returns the required year but I don't know how to incorporate it (or a better alternative) into the statement above:

```sql
select
    case
      when month(sysdate) > 6 then 
        year(sysdate)
      else
        year(sysdate)-1
    end year
  from dual
```

Thanks

Comment: Side observation: your "WHERE START_DATE > '01-JUL-2020'" is comparing START_DATE (supposedly defined as DATE) to a character string that _you_ (not oracle) recognizes as a date.  This forces oracle to perform an implied to_date that may or may not work.  What you should do is "WHERE START_DATE > to_date('01-JUL-2020','dd-MON-yyyy')"   But kudos for at least using 4-digit years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have a built-in `month` function so I'm assuming that is a user-defined function that you've created.  Assuming that's the case, it sounds like you want

```
where start_date > (case when month(sysdate) > 6
                         then trunc(sysdate,'yyyy') + interval '6' month
                         else trunc(sysdate,'yyyy') - interval '6' month
                      end)
```

Comment: It looks like Oracle does have a month function, I haven't created a function for this.

Comment: @Pedro - Not by default.  If you try in a default database, you'll get an error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aae8c3578f1f4bc1f0665b8ee4c6b011 Maybe someone else created it.  If your database was migrated from some other platform, many migration tools create functions that mimic the behavior of the source platform.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract six months and compare the dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE trunc(add_months(sysdate, -6), 'YYYY') = trunc(start_date, 'YYYY')
```

This compares the year of the date six months ago to the year on the record -- which seems to be the logic you want.